# Responsive pictures not diplaying well in ONLY one scenario

Tags: jquery, css

I have a jQuery script that when an icon picture is clicked, the script checks whether the icon is portrait or landscap, then open the same picture but bigger. To make it responsive for small screens, the bigger picture should fit perfectly well without loosing its ratio, regardless if the device is in portrait or landscape mode.

```
$(".imageInner").click(function() {
    var imgRatio = ($(this).width() / $(this).height());
    var imgClass = (imgRatio > 1) ? 'landscape' : 'portrait';
    $(".viewImage").addClass(imgClass);
    var imgsrc = $(this).attr("src").match(/[^\.]+/) + "_B.jpg";
    $(".viewImage").append("<img src=' " + imgsrc + " '/>");
    $(".xButton").fadeIn(2000); 
});

$(".xButton").click(function() { //this is to close the picture div
    $(".pageOuterContainer").show();
    $(".xButton").hide();
    $(".viewImage_Container").toggle("slow");
    $(".viewImage").empty(); 
    });
```

This is the css file

```
.viewImage { display: inline-block; text-align: center;  vertical-align: middle; } 


@media only screen and (orientation:landscape)  
{   
    .portrait { height: 100%; width: 99%;}
    .portrait img {height: 100%;  width: auto; }
    .landscape { height: 100%; width: 99%;}
    .landscape img {height: 100%;  width: auto; } 
} 


@media only screen and (orientation:portrait)
{   
    .portrait { height: 100%; width: 99%;}
    .portrait img {height: 100%;  width: auto; }
    .landscape { height: auto; width: 99%; }
    .landscape img { height: auto; width: 100%; } 
}
```

The script works perfectly well at all times except in one scenario. If I click on a landscape picture when the device screen is in portrait mode, the big picture is displayed well. BUT if I then click on a portrait picture, the big picture is misplaced. In other words this error occurs ONLY when I click on a portrait icon, after I had clicked on a landscape icon (when the device is in portrait mode).

Any hint on how to stop this error? Is the script stocking up somewhere?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that never remove the classes landscape and portrait from `.viewImage`.

By the way, I think it could be solved without the need of difference between portrait and landscape, especially if you don't have problem loading your images as background images.

In this case you could add `background-size: contain;` to `.viewImage`. With this property the background image always fits in the container without loosing the ratio.